# What approach should I take in developing simple animation based iOS game

Tags: ios, user-interface, user-experience, uianimation

My question here is not about how to achieve something, but what all to include that would have the best effect for the content I am presenting.

I am designing an app (probably with single screen) which is story based. Not a story, but a scenario, to say. A typical scenario is driving through the street, going to office or both in one. And so on.

Upon each tap (or any user activity), next step of the scenario will reveal itself. Like meeting a person, colliding with a car and so on. But since these scenarios are virtually infinite, it is not possible to design graphics for my app. To say in other words, it won't be an office, an attic, a castle or a house. It can be any of that, or a combination of them.

Due to this limitation, and partially my laziness to deal with a lot of graphics (I don't have a subordinate, nor big bucks!), I have decided to do some simple animation upon each tap. A single object (like a ball) can roll or emerge from nowhere etc.

My questions:

1) Optional: How do I achieve this animation? I know objective c but I do not know if it suffice. Box2d is other option that I know of. Is it ok or an overkill? If objective c suffices, can anyone help me with simple code that will animate a rolling ball from far (center of the iphone)?

2) Required: Above is something I can figure out by myself, but this is more important: How do I devise my other UI to describe the scene and situation? What all iOS features would fit the best in situation? I can think of single UILabel to describe situation, but I do not know how I can position/animate it along with 1 above. Again, this seems far too simplistic however. Are there other iOS views that could help me?

Sorry for somewhat ambiguous requirement, but I am facing lack of imagination here, and I know if I am misled at this step, a lot of things can go wrong.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: First of all, nice question. Second, I am not well-rounded in games, so take my advice lightly. But do you plan to use storyboards or .xib files. If so, that would make this quite a bit easier. Say you had a single view, with a custom view inside it. You would simply add the animation on that view (Through code), but you could then still add labels or whatever else. Actually, reverse that. But that labels on the custom view, and animate the main view. I'm not sure how well that would work, but it is an idea.

Comment: Thanks. What kind of app should I create? will it be opengl or single view based application? The kinds of animations I expect is 2 or 3 max. Not more than that. How would that go?

Comment: Yes, I am comfortable with storyboards.

Comment: Well. You could do both. Storyboards contains an OpenGL view you can stop and assign to it's own class.